# React - Fetch data in the parent or inside its childs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

> Note: I am not using Redux (only Context + Hooks)

### Introduction

I have a screen "**Profile**", that renders a **TabView**.

This **TabView**, renders two components as scenes:

1. **UserPosts**
2. **UserInformation**

My Profile screen, fetches the user data from my database, as it has to render some stuff that depends on this data.

Also, it is passed down via props to my "**UserInformation**" component, as it just renders the user data. So... there is no data fetching in my "**UserInformation**" component.

In the other hand, my "**UserPosts**" component is responsible of fetching the user posts, as it renders a component "**UserPostsGrid**" which renders those posts with pagination (endless FlatList).

> Note: Data fetching is performed in custom hooks, not directly inside
> the component (also, those hooks manages the respective stateful
> data).

### Problem

The main problem comes when I need to refresh the *user data* and the *user posts* when the user pull-to-refresh inside the "**Profile**" screen.

There is no problem for this screen to fetch the user data, as I have said before the "**Profile**" screen is responsible of that action.

But the posts are the stateful data of my child...

### Multiple solutions?

I have thought to solve this problem using the current solution:

```
React.forwardRef() + React.useImperativeHandle()
```

With this, I will be able to pass a ref to my "**UserPosts**" and use imperative programming for accessing the data fetching method: `userPostsRef.current.refreshPosts();`

I have never seen other scenarios for solving this problem like this, but it should work. Instead, other coders implement a ContextProvider to handle all the data and be able to access it wherever they want. The main problem I notice here is: extra memoization + extra re-renders.

Another solution might be to implement all the data fetching inside the parent, and pass the respective callbacks via props to the child. The main problem I notice here is that we are creating some kind of "God Component" and we might have multiple lines of code...

### My question

**Is it an anti-pattern or a bad practice** to implement the first solution **?**

Comment: Yes it is an antipattern because now component depends on parent which it should not know anything about. Either use context/redux or pass callbacks as prop and control data in parent component. This is how it is meant to be.

Comment: `As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases.` I'd say this would be one of those cases.

Comment: My recipe would be Redux for state management + Reselect for smart selectors + Redux Saga for API calls.

Comment: @CodeSpirit I think that the child component is not depending on the parent at all. I mean, it is the parent the one that depends on the children. If you simply render the child without passing the ref, you will not be able to use its "refresh" method, which is supposed to be used with pull-to-refresh (maybe in a parent component). The children component by itself will be able to do its respective functionality (the one that doesn't depend on pull-to-refresh).

Comment: @kasav BTW, if I decouple the logic of fetching to a parent component or the state management to a context provider, respectively, the child will depend on the parent (problem?) or on that context (no problem with this). At least, this is what I think. I mean, there will be no re-usability if I move the logic of the children to the parent.

Comment: In this particular case I don't know why it is an anti-pattern, it makes the component more reusable and flexible (because it is an independent recipe of all its information and logic) than using the "callbacks as props" solution. What if I wanna move that component to another screen in order to render it without the current parent?

Answer (score 1):

#### To answer your question:

Yes, it [is an antipattern in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle), because React is built around the idea that you specify the state of your app, and then let React render the components depending on this given state.

If something should change, you are supposed to specify a new state that represents the difference to the old state.

Refs should only be used if there is no other option. Basically, if you use Refs you say "I don't want to use React for this specific part of my code".

> As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases

#### To use state instead of commands:

I would approach this kind of problem by trying to **translate the *imperative action* into some *state of information***.

- The user says "get me the latest data", that is a command, i.e. *imperative*.
- Now I would ask "what is the user telling me about the state of the data right now ?"
- An answer would be "this data is not up to date anymore", and this can be expressed as a state, and passed around via props.

#### A solution for your problem:

E.g. you might use a prop `needsUpdate`, which is set to `true` when the data should be updated, and to `false` when fetched.

To avoid unnecessary renders (setting `needsUpdate = false` would cause another call of e.g. useEffect, even if nothing happens there), I probably would use a child component prop like `latestUpdateRequest` and a child state like `latestUpdate` which holds a counter or timestamp, and then compare `if(latestUpdateRequest > latestUpdate)`.

To inform the parent about the change just pass a callback function like `dataUpdated()` as a prop.

Comment: But, how will the parent knows that the child has finished its task? I mean, it is just a pull-to-refresh, take a look at instagram User Profile screen. When the user refreshes, the user posts are also recalculated.

Comment: just pass a callback function like `dataHasUpdated()` as a prop. I updated my answer as well.